# Pytorch: How can I find indices of first nonzero element in each row of a 2D tensor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a 2D tensor with some nonzero element in each row like this:

```
import torch
tmp = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=torch.float)
```

I want a tensor containing the index of first nonzero element in each row:

```
indices = tensor([2],
                 [3])
```

How can I calculate it in Pytorch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could find a tricky answer for my question:

```
  tmp = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=torch.float)
  idx = reversed(torch.Tensor(range(1,8)))
  print(idx)

  tmp2= torch.einsum("ab,b->ab", (tmp, idx))

  print(tmp2)

  indices = torch.argmax(tmp2, 1, keepdim=True)
  print(indeces)
```

The result is:

```
tensor([7., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.])
tensor([[0., 0., 5., 0., 3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4., 3., 0., 0.]])
tensor([[2],
        [3]])
```

Answer (score 14):

I have simplified Iman's approach to do the following:

```
idx = torch.arange(tmp.shape[1], 0, -1)
tmp2= tmp * idx
indices = torch.argmax(tmp2, 1, keepdim=True)
```

Comment: this is such an easy but smart solution!

Comment: note that if there are no non-zeros this defaults to zero as the first non-zero index.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that all the nonzero values are equal, `argmax` returns the first index.

```
tmp = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
indices = tmp.argmax(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Seppo answer, we can eliminate the assumption that "all the nonzero values are equal" by simply creating a mask from the original tensor and then using pytorch functions

```
# tmp = some tensor of whatever shape and values
indices = torch.argmax((tmp != 0).to(dtype=torch.int), dim=-1)
```

However, if a row of tensor is all zeros, then the information returned isn't the first nonzero element index. I suppose the nature of the question makes it that this case doesn't occur.